# Why data incorrectly submits to form?

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

Newb here working with forms and sql.

I have some sort of cross wiring happening in which the form input name of the eMail input ('incEmail') is actually inserting into the database instead of the value which was entered. Also any data that is entered using the form ([see here: http://zephir.seattlecentral.edu/~jstein11/itc250/z14/sandbox/w05c09__eMail.php](http://zephir.seattlecentral.edu/~jstein11/itc250/z14/sandbox/w05c09__eMail.php) ) kID remains 'zero' instead of incrementing. See screenshot, the last two entries, both list/show as '0').

To summarize, the kID stays zero for each new entry created. The data entered for the email is not begin submitted to the database, instead the name of the input field is being submitted to the database.

[image]

```
        <?php /
# '../' works for a sub-folder.  use './' for the root
require '../inc_0700/config_inc.php'; #provides configuration, pathing, error handling, db credentials
//END CONFIG AREA ----------------------------------------------------------

# Read the value of 'action' whether it is passed via $_POST or $_GET with $_REQUEST
if(isset($_REQUEST['act'])){$myAction = (trim($_REQUEST['act']));}else{$myAction = "";}

switch ($myAction)
{//check 'act' for type of process
    case "add": //2) Form for adding new report
        addReport();
        break;
    case "insert": //3) Insert new report
        insertExecute();
        break;
    default: //1)Show existing Reports
        showReport();
}
function showReport()
{//Select Report
    global $config;
    get_header();
    echo '<h3 align="center">' . smartTitle() . '</h3>';
    $sql = 'select kID, incWho, incEmail, incWhat, incWhen from incKaiju';
    $result = mysqli_query(IDB::conn(),$sql) or die(trigger_error(mysqli_error(IDB::conn()), E_USER_ERROR));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)//at least one record!
    {//show results
        echo '<table align="center" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">';
        echo '<tr>
                <th>Kaiju Incident Report</th>
                <th>eMail</th>
                <th>Officer Reporting</th>
                <th>Kaiju Identified</th>
                <th>Date of Incident</th>
            </tr>
            ';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {//dbOut() function is a 'wrapper' designed to strip slashes, etc. of data leaving db
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>Kid00' . (int)$row['kID'] . '</td>                  
                    <td>' . dbOut($row['incEmail']) . '</td>
                    <td>Officer ' . dbOut($row['incWho']) . '</td>
                    <td>' . dbOut($row['incWhat']) . '</td>
                    <td>' . dbOut($row['incWhen']) . '</td>
                </tr>
                ';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }else{//no records
      echo '<div align="center"><h3>Currently No Reports in Database.</h3></div>';
    }
    echo '<div align="center"><a href="' . THIS_PAGE . '?act=add"><br />ADD REPORT</a></div>';
    @mysqli_free_result($result); //free resources
    get_footer();
}
function addReport()
{# shows details from a single Report, and preloads their first name in a form.
    global $config;

    //Inject my styles and crap here

    $config->loadhead .= '
    <script type="text/javascript" src="' . VIRTUAL_PATH . 'include/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkForm(thisForm)
        {//check form data for valid info
            if(empty(thisForm.incWho,"Reporting Officer ")){return false;}

            if(!isEmail(thisForm.incEmail,"Please Enter a Valid Email")){return false;}
            return true;//if all is passed, submit!

            if(empty(thisForm.incWhat,"Confirm Kaiji ")){return false;}
            if(empty(thisForm.incWhen,"Date of Incident ")){return false;}
        }
    </script>';

    get_header();
    echo '
    <h3 align="center">' . smartTitle() . ' List + Add + Insert</h3>
    <h4 align="center">Enter Report</h4>
    <form action="' . THIS_PAGE . '" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    <table align="center">
       <tr><td align="right">Reporting Officer</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="incWho" />
                <font color="red"><b>*</b></font> <em>(alphanumerics & punctuation)</em>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td align="right">Email</td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="incEmail" />
                   <font color="red"><b>*</b></font> <em>(valid email only)</em>
               </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td align="right">Confirm Kaiji</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="incWhat" />
                <font color="red"><b>*</b></font> <em>(alphanumerics & punctuation)</em>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td align="right">Date of Incident </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="incWhen" />
                <font color="red"><b>*</b></font> <em>(alphanumerics & punctuation)</em>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <input type="hidden" name="act" value="insert" />
       <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Report"><em>(<font color="red"><b>*</b> required field</font>)</em>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <div align="center"><a href="' . THIS_PAGE . '">Exit (Do not submit Incident Report)</a></div>
    ';
    get_footer();
}

function insertExecute()
{
    $iConn = IDB::conn();//must have DB as variable to pass to mysqli_real_escape() via iformReq()
    $redirect = THIS_PAGE; //global var used for following formReq redirection on failure
    $incWho = strip_tags(iformReq('incWho', $iConn));
    $Email = strip_tags(iformReq('incEmail',$iConn));//if no email then comment line out
    $incWhat = strip_tags(iformReq('incWhat', $iConn));
    $incWhen = strip_tags(iformReq('incWhen', $iConn));
    //next check for specific issues with data
    if(!ctype_graph($_POST['incWho'])|| !ctype_graph($_POST['incWhat'])|| !ctype_graph($_POST['incWhen']))
    {//data must be alphanumeric or punctuation only
        feedback("Data submitted may only contain letters, numbers or punctuation");
        myRedirect(THIS_PAGE);
    }
    if(!onlyEmail($_POST['incEmail']))
    {//data must be alphanumeric or punctuation only
        feedback("Data entered for email is not valid");
        myRedirect(THIS_PAGE);
    }
    //build string for SQL insert with replacement vars, %s for string, %d for digits
    $sql = "INSERT INTO incKaiju (incWho, incEmail, incWhat, incWhen) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')";
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO incKaiju (incWho, incEmail, incWhat, incWhen) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s',NOW())";
    # sprintf() allows us to filter (parameterize) form data
    $sql = sprintf($sql,$incWho,incEmail,$incWhat,$incWhen);
    @mysqli_query($iConn, $sql) or die(trigger_error(mysqli_error($iConn), E_USER_ERROR));
    #feedback success or failure of update
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($iConn) > 0)
    {//success!  provide feedback, chance to change another!
        feedback("Report added successfully!","notice"); //notice changes color to red!
    }else{//Problem!  Provide feedback!
        feedback("Report failed to submit!");
    }
    myRedirect(THIS_PAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue with the email:

```
$sql = sprintf($sql,$incWho,$incEmail,$incWhat,$incWhen);
```

You're missing a $ there.

If the kid column is not auto-increment, it will not automatically increment on a new insert. Modify the table accordingly in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE incKaiju CHANGE kID kID INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the database is now auto incrementing and the 'incEmail' is not inserting into the database so that is good. unfortunately, the email isn't inserting into the database so something is still off...

Comment: Ok. Check out `$Email = strip_tags(iformReq('incEmail',$iConn));` Replace $Email by $incEmail

Comment: Thank you very much (Can I be you when i grow up?)